# Get index of element in array

Tags: contract-development, arrays

I am trying to delete an element from an array without knowing its index in the array. Is there a way to delete an element from an array based off of its value not its index?

Something like:

index = array.find(element)

delete array[index]

Answer (score 0):

There's no implementation of the findByElement of array in Solidity.

But you can achieve this several ways:

- Write your own function to find element, can be simple as:

```
function findElementInArray(element, arr) public returns(int) {
    bytes32 encodedElement = keccak256(abi.encode(element.id));
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (encodedElement == keccak256(abi.encode(element.id))) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

- Use a mapping to keep the ref from the object into the index of the element in array

```
mapping(_YourObject -> int) arrayIndexes

// delete object:
delete array(arrayIndexes[object])
```

Answer (score 0):

I got one, you can use it as a library.

```js
library Array {
    function removeElement(uint256[] storage _array, uint256 _element) public {
        for (uint256 i; i<_array.length; i++) {
            if (_array[i] == _element) {
                _array[i] = _array[_array.length - 1];
                _array.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Import this into code, and call it like this: `yourArray.removeElement(element)`

Works in this way: loop over an array, if the indexed element is there, overwrite the searched element with the last element and `.pop()` the last item of the array.

Limitations are the size of the array since you have to loop over it and the **array must contain only unique elements**. I'm not entirely sure, but technically if you remove `break` it can work for a non-unique array as well.